# Minimizing the probability of a draw in a democratic poll

Tags: probability, combinatorics, voting-theory

A group of **$k$ people** wants to choose democratically between **$n$ possible options**. They arrange a poll in which **every person votes for $r$ out of the $n$ options without repetition**, meaning there are $n \choose r$ possible choices per person. The highest scoring option will be the winning choice - unless there's a draw of course...

> **Question:** Assuming each person chooses $r$ out of $n$ options with uniform probability. What is the value of $r$ for which the probability of the poll ending in a draw is minimal? Hopefully the answer will be unique and in a closed form $r=f(k,n)$.

Sadly beyond trivial remarks about the extreme cases (like $r=n$ implies draw will happen with full probability and $r,k << n$ implies draw will be pretty likely because of sparse voting) I have nothing valuable to say about my attempts so far.

Edit: To anyone who downvotes this - please explain what you think is wrong with the question. To make things clear: **This is not a homework problem!**. Still, if you think this is a trivial problem please explain your solution - if not then please reconsider the downvote.

Comment: Please show your try at the question because it doesn't seem to be a badly proposed one and I hope it wouldn't be closed as off-topic.

Comment: This may or may not be the solution (and I certainly don't know how to rigorously prove it): Let $X_i =$ the no. of votes for option $i$.  Then $X_i$ is a simple Binomial akin to flipping $k$ coins each with probability of success $= \frac{r}{n}$.  The VARIANCE of $X_i$ is maximized when probability $=\frac{1}{2}$, i.e. when $r = n/2$ (round up or down if necessary, doesnt matter which).  Intuitively it would seem ties are less likely when variance is maximized?  Proving this seems difficult though: (1) we only care about ties at the most popular choice, (2) $X_i, X_j$ are dependent...

Comment: @antkam I don't think your solution has the correct asymptotic. When $k >> n$ the possiblity of a draw will be very likely since as $k$ goes to $\infty$ the mean number of votes for a given option approaches the expectation value of votes for the option (by law of large numbers) so whatever the mean is (it will depend on $r$ perhaps) it will be identical for all options. This is a heuristic but I find it pretty convincing towards the fact that $r$ should depend on both $k$ and $n$.

Comment: @SaalHardali - I thought about your point too, but for any $k$ (even large $k$), it is certainly true that $X_i \sim Binomial(k, \frac{r}{n})$, because every voter has $\frac{r}{n}$ chance of voting for $i$, and the voters are independent.  And $Binomial(k, p)$ has variance $kp(1-p)$, which for any given $k$ is maximized at $p=1/2$.  What happens is that as $k$ increases, the law of large number helps to narrow the distribution of $X_i/k$ (this fraction would $\rightarrow p$), but the LLN does NOT narrow the distribution of $X_i$ itself.  (Indeed the standard deviation grows as $\sqrt{k}$.)

Comment: @antkam I see. Well, If anything this convinces me even further that this is a subtle and tricky question.

Comment: @SaalHardali - e.g. consider $n=10, r=5, k=10^6$.  On average each option gets half a million votes, but breaking ties is really easy because of all the digits, e.g. $510428$ would beat $510417$ with no ties.

Comment: @antkam Good point! Silly of me to miss that. I'm still not convinced that $r$ is independent of $k$ though. At least asymptotically it is though.

Comment: I'm working on an answer involving configurations of the voting grid. Anyone here can feel free to edit it: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11275/364722

Answer (score 6):

We treat this rigorously for $k=2$, and conjecturally for all $k$.

**For $k=2$, we find $r \sim \sqrt{n}$.**

When A and B each vote $r$ options, they avoid a tie iff B chooses $1$ option already chosen by A, and then chooses $(r-1)$ options not chosen by A.  So the probability of avoiding a tie is
$$p=r {n-r \choose r-1} \ / \ {n \choose r}.$$
This probability can not be maximized at a boundary like $r=0$ or $r=n$, since those give a probability of $0$, so it must be maximized somewhere where the discrete derivative is roughly $0$.

The optimal $r$ will therefore
be a solution to
$$\frac{r {n-r \choose r-1}}{ {n \choose r}} \sim
\frac{(r+1) {n-r-1 \choose r}}{ {n \choose r+1}}.$$
We can actually solve this:  Cross-multiplying and cancelling reduces it to
$$r^2(n-r)^2 \sim (r+1)^2(n-2r)(n-2r+1).$$
Neglecting the final $+1$ and square-rooting leads to a quadratic whose solution is
$$r \sim \sqrt{n+1} -1.$$
To a first approximation $r\sim\sqrt{n}$, and more precisely $r$ is an integer within $2$ of $\sqrt{n}$.

**Generalization for higher k**

This suggests a strategy for higher $k$, namely targeting an expectation that exactly one option will receive two votes.

The $k,n,r$ scenario leads to exactly one option getting two votes with probability
$$p=\frac{{n \choose kr-1}(kr-1)!(k-1)r^2}
{\left({n \choose r}r!\right)^k}$$

Meanwhile the expected number of options receiving two votes is
$$n{k \choose 2}\left(\frac{r}{n}\right)^2 \left(\frac{n-r}{n}\right)^{k-2}.$$ 
So we choose
$$r \sim \sqrt{n/{k \choose 2}}$$
and for large $n$, this avoids ties with limiting probability $$p \sim \frac{2}{ke}.$$

Comment: Nice. Do you think this approximation will be valid for any k?

Comment: Oh boy, and I hoped for a closed formula...

Comment: @MattF. very interesting solution for the $k=2$ special case.  But while something like $\sqrt{n/{k \choose 2}}$ might maximize the probability of exactly one option receiving >1 votes, the best way to break ties (for $k>2$) might allow many options to have >1 votes, as long as the top vote-getter's votecount is unique.

Comment: @antkam: Certainly that's right.  We can set the expected votes per option anywhere from $0$ to $k$ (in increments of $k/n$).  For $k\gg 1$, setting the expected votes around $k/2$ gives a spread of order $\pm \sqrt{k}$ in the number of votes per option, and so if $\sqrt{k} \gg n$, we don't expect ties at all.  This approach, by contrast, virtually guarantees ties for larger $k$.

Answer (score 6):

I think this is quite difficult.

Here's a simulation with $n=15$, $k=6$. The abscisa is $r$, in blue (right axis) we have the probability of draw, and in red (left axis) the average votes for the winner.

I cannot be sure about programming errors, but I'm quite sure that the striking uglyness  of the blue line (the one that determines the minimum we are interested in, i.e, $r=f(k,n)$) is not due to statistical noise - each run consists of 10^6 trials, and different simulations give practically the same values.

[image]

In case you are interested, [here's the source](https://ideone.com/X1lXXi) (mind you, you need to keep the number of tries low if you want to run it in Ideone).

Update: Here's the same graph for $n=100$, $k=5$. Honestly, I find that oscillation totally unexpected and hard to believe, but...

[image]

... but it seems that that surprising oscillation also appears in the somewhat simpler model (it can be evaluated numerically, at least) in which each vote is iid Bernoulli with $p=r/n$ (or equivalently, where the number of votes by each voter follows a Binomial distribution with mean $r$). Interesting.

Update 2: In the (not the same but similar) model in mentioned above, the probability of draw is given by

$$\begin{align} P_d(n,k,p) &= 1-
n \sum_{m=1}^k B(m;p,k) \left[\sum_{t=0}^{m-1}
B(t;p,k) \right]^{n-1}\\
&=
1- n \sum_{m=1}^k p^{m} (1-p)^{k-m} \binom{k}{m} \left[\sum_{t=0}^{m-1}
p^{t} (1-p)^{k-t} \binom{k}{t} \right]^{n-1}
\end{align} \tag{1}
$$

where $p=r/n$, and $B(m;p,k)$ is the Binomial distribution with parameters $p,k$, evaluated at $m$. We should expect this model to give similar results to the original one, at least for not-so-small values of $n,r$; and indeed numerical experimentation seem to confirm this (green line in the graph above corresponds to $P_d$ in $(1)$).

Sadly, it doesn't seem easy to study the behaviour of $P_d$ in $(1)$ with respect to $p$, nor even asymptotically...

Added: more graphs of $P_d$, for $n=1000$, and $k=5,7,9,23$.

[image]

BTW, Matt F.'s answer seems to fit quite well with the first minimum (which is also the only local minimum for $k=2$).